# xcode : how to disable gesture recognizer out of some view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I have a one tap gesture recognizer for an uiimageView, enabling user to tap and add uiTextField anywhere he tapes on this uiimageview.

The problem that sometimes i get my textfield out (near) of my uiimageview. I want that the textfield doesn't anyway exceed the uiimageview frame.

here is my code in ViewDidLoad :

```
// Create gesture recognizer
recognizer = 
[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addText:)] autorelease];

// Set required taps and number of touches
[recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

// Add the gesture to the view
[self.img addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and in the method addText:

```
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:[self view]];

UITextField * textFld = [[UITextField alloc]init];

[textFld setDelegate:self];

[textFld addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

[textFld setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"System Bold" size:fontSize]];

CGRect frame ;    
frame.origin.x = point.x;
frame.origin.y = point.y; 
frame.size.width=300;
frame.size.height=80;

textFld.frame=frame;

[self.img addSubview:textFld];

[textFld release];
```

and finally imageMoved:withEvent:

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
UIControl *control = sender;
control.center = point;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` method in your `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to see where the touch occurred and decide whether or not you want to respond to the gesture.  Return `NO` if the touch is too close to the edge of your UIImageView, otherwise return `YES`.  Or simply check the `touch.view` to see if the touch occurred on your `UIImageView`.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```